# Angular 2 Services Unit Testing with DarkSkyApi call

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular2-services

I hope you can help. I search in the whole internet for answer to my questions. I new in programming with Angular 2 and all answers i find are to crypticle to me.

so thats my question. I will test a service in angular 2 with karma. And have the DarkskyApi in Use at the Service:

```
//imports
import DarkSkyApi from 'dark-sky-api';  

@Injectable()
export class WetterService {

  /***
   * Konstruktor
   */
  constructor() {
    this.skyApi = this.InitDarkSky();
  }

  /**
   * Die Verbindung zur API Darksky initalialisiern
   */
  private InitDarkSky(): IDarkSkyApi {
    const darksky: IDarkSkyApi = new DarkSkyApi(this.ApiKey);

    // Ansteuern der Api
    return darksky
      .units('si')
      .language('de');
  }
}
```

and this is the test to the service:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { WetterService } from './wetter.service';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import DarkSkyApi from 'dark-sky-api';

describe('WetterService', () => {
  let darkSkyApi: DarkSkyApi;

  beforeEach(() => {
    darkSkyApi = new DarkSkyApi();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        WetterService
      ],
      imports: [HttpClientModule]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([WetterService], (service: WetterService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

When i run the test i become follow error:

TypeError: dark_sky_api_1.default is not a constructor

I hope so you can help.

Thanks,
Steffen

Comment: My git to the project:
https://github.com/kaemmi84/kiwiGridWetter

Comment: are you sure you are calling the DarkSkyApi constructor correctly.

Comment: What is `darkSkyApi = new DarkSkyApi();` supposed to be doing in your test? You don't actually use that instance, and it doesn't match the way you create it in the production code. Where does the error come from?

Comment: hey there,
sorry I dosen´t see your answers.
yes the error comes from the initalisation. I have change the code. this is my [modul](https://github.com/kaemmi84/kiwiGridWetter/blob/master/src/app/wetter/wetter.module.ts) and this is the [service](https://github.com/kaemmi84/kiwiGridWetter/blob/master/src/app/service/wetter.service.ts) and this is the [test of the service](https://github.com/kaemmi84/kiwiGridWetter/blob/master/src/app/service/wetter.service.spec.ts). On test i become the error 'Can't resolve all parameters for WetterService: (?)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you create a new instance instead of having an DI. You could propably add DarkSkiApi via Factory. This is just blind coded.

in app.module.ts

```
providers: [{
  provide: DarkSkyApi,
  useFactory: DarkSkyApiFactory
}]
```

then you have a factory

```
import DarkSkyApi from 'dark-sky-api';

export function DarkSkyApiFactory(): JwtHelper {
 return new DarkSkyApi('API_KEY');
}
```

in your service it will look like this:

```
  export class WetterService {
     constructor(private darkSkyApi: DarkSkyApi) {
       this.darksky
           .units('si')
           .language('de');
     } 
  }
```

and then you can easily mock the API in your test

```
    wetterService = new WetterService(fakeApi as DarkSkyApi);
    class fakeApi = {
     units(unit: string) {}
     language(language: string) {}
    };
```

This is really just a basic Idea how to rewrite your code to be better testable

Comment: Thanks Carsten for your fast answer,

I have refactor my code. And the App works!
But I don´t know how I can change my Service Test:

https://github.com/kaemmi84/kiwiGridWetter/blob/master/src/app/service/wetter.service.spec.ts

 I had push my change in my git. Thanks

Comment: Great to hear that your app works, but I don't get what you want to change. For service spec I usually avoid using a testBed. See https://angular.io/guide/testing#services

Comment: Yes I work also with testBed. You can See in my link above. Sorry i am new with this. I need help to initziate my service.

Comment: in that case I would add to providers something like {use: DarkSkyApi, useClass: FakeDarkSkyApi }  - then the DI will be resolved and it will take your fake class instead of real class

Comment: hey carsten, thanks to your patience. I had checkin my last codechange in the git: https://github.com/kaemmi84/kiwiGridWetter/blob/master/src/app/service/wetter.service.spec.ts

and become a new error: Can't resolve all parameters for WetterService: (?)

Thanks so much